# How to automate SharePoint site creation programatically?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-2016

For one of the requirements, I have to implement automated site creation using information entered in a list. Basically on the New item click in the list, user would enter details such as Client Name (would be the site title while site creation takes place), Project (text field to enter project number). What would be a generalized approach to automate the site creation using information entered in a SharePoint list?
i am using the office 365/SharePoint online platform.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two options:

For completely automated and additions to the list, create a SharePoint 2013 style workflow and use REST web services to create the subsites (_api/web/webinfos/add). You would send the request from the workflow using JSON like this:

```
{"parameters":{ "__metadata":{"type":"SP.WebInfoCreationInformation"},
                   "Url":"testsub",
                   "Title":"Test subsite",
                   "Description":"This is test site",
                   "Language":1033,
                   "WebTemplate":"sts#0",
                   "UseUniquePermissions":"false" } }
```

For administrator automation of the process, use the PowerShell SharePoint PNP cmdlets to create the sites.

Comment: Thanks for your Response Mike.

Comment: One more question Mike, is there any way we could do this using JSOM?

Comment: Yes, for the "Classic UI". Just add the JavaScript code to the New form. Keep in mind that users might also use the "Modern UI" new panel, or the DataGrid view and not trigger your JavaScript.